# PHP - Two pages, two sessions, same values

Tags: php, session, session-variables

If two websites use the same session variables (they share the same code that I've written) and I have them open in the same browser (in two tabs), the session for SiteA gets mixed up with SiteB's values and vice versa. For example, if I set `$_SESSION['var1']=1` in SiteA and then open SiteB in the same browser and perform an `array_dump($_SESSION)` then I see `var1` in the dump.

What can I do to have a set of session variables stay within the "scope" of only one site?

Comment: This is why I rename always all variables when I work on two sites on the same server and recycle the code....

Comment: @bikey77, @TRiG is asking whether the two tabs are open on the same domain or not (i.e. is one tab `http://sitea.mydomain.com` and the other on `http://siteb.mydomain.com`, or are both tabs `http://site.mydomain.com`?)

Comment: @vladr. I'm assuming that they're on `example.com/SiteA` and `example.com/SiteB` (i.e., the same domain), because that's the most likely interpretation. (Iupatus's answer makes the same assumption.)

Comment: @TRiG: No, they are different completely domains. Of course, the problem occurs also when running on the same machine (localhost).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose those sessions are under same domain and both are using same session cookie name. Change names for this sessions using `session_name` (before you'll run `session_start`).

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php

Comment: No, the sessions are on different domains.

Comment: completely different, or you mean subdomains of one domain?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add some prefix to your session variables to distinguish one from the other ?

**E.g.**

```
siteA_loggedIn
siteB_loggedIn
```

Comment: Why should one do that? Setting different session names on both sites should be enough...

Answer (score 0):

If you have two separate sites running on the same domain name, they will indeed share session data by default, but you can change that. The name of the session cookie is set in `php.ini` as the `session.name` directive (by default, it's `PHPSESSID`), but you can overwrite that with `session_name()`.

What you want to do is to call the session cookie on one site `SessionSiteA` instead (note, the session name [must be alphanumeric, and must contain at least one letter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php)).

So your options are (a) have a different `php.ini` file for each site; (b) overwrite the value in `.htaccess` (this is allowed for some, but not all, `php.ini` settings, and I can't currently work out how to do it for `session.name`: it may not be possible); or (c) call the `session_name()` function in one of the sites before setting or reading any sessions. Note that `session_name()` can be [computationally expensive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php#103472), so use it with care (perhaps on one of the sites only, leaving the busier site to use the default `PHPSESSID`).

**Note:** Another option might be to save sessions from each site in a different place, using `ini_set('session.save_path', ...)` differently on each site. As above, this would have to be done centrally, before any sessions are set or used.

Comment: I added a comment to my 1st post, the sites are on different domains.

Comment: Well, that's ... weird. Are you creating the sessions in a non-standard manner?

Comment: No. I use session_start() and that's all. I can provide examples if needed.

Comment: Are the domains in any way related (subdomains of the same domain)? What `Set-Cookie` headers are the sites actually sending?

Comment: No, the sites have absolutely no relation apart from the fact that I've coded both of them.

Comment: It's malefic magic. Someone's put a curse on you. That's the only explanation.